# Why is Java generic with wildcard not allowed here?

Tags: java, generics

Following is a static function code snippet

```
   public static void safeIterate(Iterable<? extends CombatComponent> iterable, Consumer<? extends CombatComponent> consumer) {
        Iterator<? extends CombatComponent> iterator = iterable.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            consumer.accept(iterator.next());
        }
    }
```

such code snippet could not compile successfully unless I change the second function parameter to  `Consumer<CombatComponent> consumer`, which confused me a lot.

Comment: You don't want `? extends`, you would need `? super`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You might clarify that that applies to the bound on `Consumer`, not `Iterable`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman why need ? super here? I just want to consume anything that extends `CombatComponent`

Comment: Yes.  And the name for "anything that extends `CombatComponent`" is `CombatComponent`.  It's not `? extends CombatComponent`.  That's the name for "some _single_ type that extends `CombatComponent`."